# How to convert a nesting 'for' loops into one line of code in python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, image-processing, numpy-slicing

I have this code example and my task is to reduce the lines inside the dashed lines into one line of code , meaning convert the all for loops into one line of code. 
I have figured out one solution by my own which is this :

```
myMat.ravel()[::size + 1] = myMat.ravel()[::size - 1] = 1
```

I assume that  'np.logical_or'  function may help out here with combination of array slicing , in addition to my own solution.
Here is the function below . 
Thank you .

```
def myXMat(size):
    if size != np.uint64(size):
        return None
    elif size == 1:
        return 1.0

    myMat = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.float64)
    # -------------------------------------------------
    for m in range(size):
        for n in range(size):
            if m == n or m == size - n - 1:
                myMat[m, n] = 1

    # -------------------------------------------------

    return myMat
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's get the big picture; what pattern are you creating?

```
In [343]: arr = np.zeros((10,10),int)                                                          
In [344]: for m in range(10): 
     ...:     for n in range(10): 
     ...:         if m==n or m==10-n-1: 
     ...:             arr[m,n] = 1 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [345]: arr                                                                                  
Out[345]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

So that's a diagonal and its oposite?

```
In [346]: np.diag(np.ones(10,int))                                                             
Out[346]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

and flip it:

```
In [347]: np.diag(np.ones(10,int))[::-1]                                                       
Out[347]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

and sum them:

```
In [348]: _346+_347                                                                            
Out[348]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Or with indexing:

```
In [352]: arr = np.zeros((10,10),int)                                                          
In [353]: arr[np.arange(10),np.arange(10)] = 1                                                 
In [354]: arr[np.arange(10)[::-1],np.arange(10)] = 1
```

Comment: Use bit_wise or `|` instead of + with `np.diag` to cope with the dimension being an odd number.